# how to limit terms by their posts meta in get_terms function

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type named 'job' and custom taxonomy meta named 'job_category' in wordpress.
Each job can have a postmeta named 'discount' which is either a number or doesn't exist. 
Now I am trying to get all job_category terms which their posts have 'discount' meta key.
what is the solution?

Comment: the trick is that you have to find out all `jobs` that have discount. and then get `job_category` from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you have to query and select all jobs that have discount meta. then find out all the terms from that posts.

here is an example code (not tested on real website).

```
//get jobs
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'job',
    //meta query
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'discount',
            'compare'   =>  'EXISTS'
        )
    )
);
$jobs = new WP_Query( $args );

//get categories from jobs
$categories = array();
foreach( $jobs as $job ) {
    $new_cats = wp_get_object_terms( $job->ID, 'job_category' );
    $categories = array_merge(
        $categories,
        array_diff(
            $categories,
            $new_cats
        )
    );
}
```